# Protractor get all select box (option) values

Tags: angularjs, integration-testing, protractor

In my tests I needed to check if all the expected values are present in a select box. It took me a while but I finally created this helper function:

```
function getSelectValues(elementFinder)
{
  var defer = protractor.promise.defer(),
      promise = defer.promise;

  elementFinder.all(by.tagName('option')).then(function(elements)
  {
    var values = [],
        elemCount = elements.length,
        counter = 0;

    elements.forEach(function(element)
    {
      element.getAttribute('value').then(function(optionValue)
      {
        counter += 1;
        values.push(optionValue);

        if(counter === elemCount)
        {
          defer.fulfill(values);
        }
      });
    })
  });

  return promise;
}
```

It works but looks really ugly to me. Is there a better way to do it?

**EDIT:**

After another two hours of reading documentation I got my helper function reduced to:

```
getSelectValues: function(elementFinder)
{
  return elementFinder.all(by.tagName('option')).map(function(elem, index)
  {
      return elem.getAttribute('value');
  });
}

profileType = element(by.model('regObj.profileType'));
expect(getSelectValues(profileType)).toEqual(['', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']);
```

Comment: well done! you can add it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: 'how to improve my code' questions are not really  the stackoverflow way :s won't downvote, great result :)

Comment: Maybe the question does not state that clearly but I thought there must be a better way to do it. Some method I didn't find in documentation or something :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using protractor > 1.3.0, you can do the following:

```
var values = element(by.model('regObj.profileType')).
                 all(by.tagName('option')).getAttribute('value');
expect(values).toEqual(['', 'aa', 'bb', 'cc']);
```